# MySQL Configured for a Private Network but the Client cannot find the Server

Tags: mysql

I have a private network with 2 nodes:

- MySQLServer [Private IP: 10.0.0.1]
- MyNode      [Private IP: 10.0.1.1]

I have tried setting the bind-address on MySQLServer to both 10.0.0.1 and to 0.0.0.0.
I have opened up all ports for all ip addresses in the network. I confirmed this via ssh between the servers.

`sudo netstat -plunt | grep mysqld` on MySQLServer shows that the it is listening on 10.0.0.1:3306

`nmap 10.0.0.1 -Pn -p3306` on MyNode shows Host is up with 0.00053s latency

Even with all of this, MyNode using `mysql -h 10.0.0.1 -uuser -p'password'` returns back with

`ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.0.1:3306' (113)`

I have been googling for upwards of 2 hours now. What am I missing brilliant minds of Stack Overflow?

Comment: Make sure the port is open in the firewall on the server.

Comment: While I read that, I was saying well obviously I opened up ufw for port 3306. And then I remembered iptables is the real firewall. Ugh... how embarrassing... Thanks for your help Barmar.